# convergence of integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the improper integral
$$
\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}v\left(v-a\right)^{-3/2}e^{-\frac{b}{2\tau(v-a)}}dv,
$$
where $a$, $b$, and $\tau$ are real constants. From my calculations, it appears that the value of this integral is $+\infty$, and so the integral fails to exist. Can someone else please confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that this integral is equal to $+\infty$ (and as such, "exists"):

the integrand is $>0$ and as $v\to+\infty$, it is equivalent to $v^{-1/2}$, whose integral at $+\infty$ diverges.